# TeamCity: error TS1148 building typescript modules

Tags: msbuild, typescript, teamcity

I'm trying to add typescript modules to a build. The solution builds fine from the IDE, from MSBuild on the command line, and even on Visual Studio Online. However, when I build in TeamCity I get the following error:

```
 C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cbd612042b438c8c\web\LobApp\CatBallBusinessWeb\Scripts\PurchaseOrderModule.ts(2, 15): error TS1148: Build: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
```

Apparently, the TeamCity build isn't picking up the right typescript.targets file. The line below from "C:\Program Files (x86)\msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScrip\Microsoft.TypeScript.targetst" is where the --module compiler flag should be applied.

```
 <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptModuleKind)' != '' and '$(TypeScriptModuleKind)' != 'none'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --module $(TypeScriptModuleKind)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
```

In the relevant project settlings, under "TypeScript Build", I have the "AMD" Module system selected.. which shouldd trigger the line above.

The TeamCity build log differs from the build log I see when I compile with MSBuild from the command line here:

TeamCity:

> [18:15:07] : [web\LobApp\CatBallBusinessWeb\CatBallBusinessWeb.csproj]
>   PreComputeCompileTypeScript [18:15:07] : [PreComputeCompileTypeScript]
>   Using "VsTsc" task from assembly "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll".
>   [18:15:07] : [PreComputeCompileTypeScript] VsTsc [18:15:07] : [VsTsc]
>   Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript [18:15:07] : [VsTsc] Task Parameter:ToolExe=tsc.exe
>   [18:15:07] : [VsTsc] Task Parameter:Configurations= --sourcemap
>   --target ES5 --noEmitOnError COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY [18:15:07] : [VsTsc] Task Parameter:
>       FullPathsToFiles=
>           Areas\Manage\Scripts\PurchaseOrderModule.ts
>           Scripts\App\Purchase\PurchaseOrderEdit.ts
>           Scripts\PurchaseOrderModule.ts
>           Scripts\PurchaseOrderIndex.ts
>           Scripts\typings\jquery\jquery.d.ts
>           Scripts\typings\knockout.mapping\knockout.mapping.d.ts
>           Scripts\typings\knockout.validation\knockout.validation.d.ts
>           Scripts\typings\knockout\knockout.d.ts
>           Scripts\typings\moment\moment-node.d.ts
>           Scripts\typings\moment\moment.d.ts

Vs. MSBuild command line:

> Target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" in file **"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
>   from project
>   "D:\dev\web\lobapp\CatBallBusinessWeb\CatBallBusinessWeb.csproj"
>   (target "CompileTypeScript" depends on it):** Using "VsTsc" task from
>   assembly "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll".
>   Task "VsTsc"   Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript   Task Parameter:ToolExe=tsc.exe
>   Task Parameter:Configurations= --module AMD --sourcemap --target ES5
>   --noEmitOnError COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY   Task Parameter:
>         FullPathsToFiles=
>             Areas\Manage\Scripts\PurchaseOrderModule.ts
>             Scripts\App\Purchase\PurchaseOrderEdit.ts
>             Scripts\PurchaseOrderModule.ts
>             Scripts\PurchaseOrderIndex.ts
>             Scripts\typings\jquery\jquery.d.ts
>             Scripts\typings\knockout.mapping\knockout.mapping.d.ts
>             Scripts\typings\knockout.validation\knockout.validation.d.ts
>             Scripts\typings\knockout\knockout.d.ts
>             Scripts\typings\moment\moment-node.d.ts
>             Scripts\typings\moment\moment.d.ts

The **highlighted** part is missing from the TeamCity log.

In TeamCity, I'm building the solution directly.. the same one that builds fine everywhere else. I have Visual Studio 2015 tools selected. I should also mention that this solution builds from the command line from the TeamCity work directory.

I'm not a build, teamcity, or typescript expert. So I'm not sure how to investigate this further. How can I figure out why the right targets file isn't being run? Given that this builds fine everywhere else, I feel like it's a TeamCity bug. On the other hand, I can't imagine how TeamCity is running MSBuild wrong.

Any help appreciated.